# change css of body on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get an highlighting effect on some various div container while the rest of the site should be dampened down in opacity including the background-image.
Any idea?

Why does this code not work? tried `.hover()` instead of `.mouseover()` too but the function won't react on any input...

```
$(function () {
    $('body').mouseover(function () {
        $('body').prop({
            "background-color": "red";
        });
    });
});
```

Another try would be to set a frame around the `body` tag in the html and then set props to that frame while the hovered frame is in normal state but I have no idea how to do this. Just beginning with js dev. :)

EDIT: did a fail...

```
$(function () {
    $('body').mouseover(function () {
        $('body').css({
            "opacity": "0.3";
        });
    });
});
```

should be that way...
any way to apply the opacity to the background image too?!

Comment: I don't understand.. When you want that effect to happen?

Comment: Can you show us what your HTML page looks like?

Comment: http://jakob-wedemyer.de/HHDA_dev/trainer/ there you go. i want to "highlight" the persons on hover. the borders are only set for dev purposes

Answer (score 0):

`.prop()` will set the property for a particular element. In your case you have to use `.css()` to set the style. Please read [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to see the difference.

Try this,

```
      $(function(){
            $('body').mouseover(function(){
                $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
            });
        });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FKPr3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/J88kJ/)</kbd>

Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Set one or more CSS properties for the set of matched elements.

```
$(function () {
    $('body').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "red"
        });
        //or $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
});
```

[this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

---

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2)

> Set one or more properties for the set of matched elements.

Comment: @JakobJJWedemeyer are you including jQuery library ?

Comment: yep
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

Comment: That `src` value doesn't look right, you should add http:// to the start so it doesn't look like a relative path. `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/vZgYy/)**</kbd>

```
body {
  background: gray;
  min-height: 1000px; /* For demo purposes */
}
```

css

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css({ backgroundColor: 'red' });
  });
});
```

animate

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: 'red' }, 600);
  });
});
```

***Note:** For some reason it doesn't work with jQuery 1.x(edge).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might want: a "dim" DIV element that adds a semi transparent black box on the entire page, that puts itself "below" the DIV you want to highlight, and then some javascript to turn it off and on, and rearrange the z indexes. The HTML would look something like this:

```
this is some text
<div id="div1" class="dimmable">hello</div>
<div id="div2" class="dimmable">goodbye</div>
<div id="dim"></div>
```

And then the JS:

```
$('div.dimmable').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', 101);
    $('#dim')
      .css('z-index', 100)
      .width($(window).innerWidth())
      .height($(window).innerHeight())
      .fadeIn();
}, function() {
    var dimmable = $(this);
    $('#dim').fadeOut({complete: function() {
        dimmable.css('z-index', 99);
    }});
});
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/GpQk4/).

A slight catch: the DIVs need to have `position:relative`, otherwise you can't change their z-indexes and you can't put them on top of the "dim" DIV. Also, anything with a higher z-index will not stay behind the "dim", of course, but you can just use higher numbers as a workaround.

Comment: I tried to get into this and tested to apply this to the page as we are going for a new approach for it. The only thing is: the script does nothing on my page.
I'm not good in JS and so don't have a clue what ive done wrong but the debugger says nothing about the script too.
maybe you can have a look at it and tell me whats wrong.
[my site](http://jakob-wedemyer.de/HHDA_dev/trainer)